# Sending messages between classes with Func Delegates

Tags: c#, delegates

I can trying to use a func delegate to send messages to another class. I normally do this with a regular delegate but I am trying to learn how to do this with Func. With the below example, I want AClass to update the main class with messages. As you can see, I am having trouble.

**Updated:** I updated the example to provide better detail. In the example I show how I use a delegate to communicate to the main class. Is it possible to do this using the func delegate?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AClass aClass = new AClass();
        // old way
        aClass.MessageEvent += new AClass.MessageEventHandler(ProcessMessage);
        aClass.MessageSender(50);

        // new way
        Func<int, String> fDelegate = aClass.MessageSender;            
        Console.WriteLine(fDelegate(10));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void ProcessMessage(String mess) {

        Console.WriteLine("Process message here: " + mess);
    }
}

class AClass {

    public event MessageEventHandler MessageEvent;
    public delegate void MessageEventHandler(String value);

    public AClass() {           
    }

    public String MessageSender(int i) {

        InvokeMessage("Message: " + i);
        return "Message: " + i;                                
    }

    public void InvokeMessage(String mess) {

        this.MessageEvent("Message sent via delegate: " + mess);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Process message here: Message sent via delegate: Message: 50
Process message here: Message sent via delegate: Message: 10
Message: 10
```

Any advice is appreciated. thx

Comment: What do you need advice on? I could advise you that you don't need a delegate to send messages to another class. Just call a method on the other class. Or I could advise you that there's nothing special about a Func delegate. It's just a delegate.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do. Tell us what you think should happen AND in which order the various InvokeMessage, ProcessMessage should be called AND by whom

Comment: Can you show how you do it with a "normal" delegate?

Comment: Your code works and you are not giving enough details on what you need to improve or fix/enhance.

Comment: @DavidePiras "Your code works"... I would say "Your code compiles and does something" :-)

Comment: Thank for the comments. I updated the main thread with details... hope this explains my question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i understand what you are attempting to accomplish. From what i understand you want to used a delegate to process data in the main class from the AClass. There are lots of ways to do this even with the generic delegates but here is one example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AClass aClass = new AClass();
        aClass.MessageDelegate = ProcessMessage;
        // Send Message (writing of output unnecessary as it happens via the delegate anyway)
        Console.WriteLine(aClass.MessageSender(50));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used as delegate (messages passed from AClass to here)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mess"></param>
    public static void ProcessMessage(String mess)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Process message here: " + mess);
    }

    class AClass
    {
        public Action<string> MessageDelegate
        { get; set; }

        public AClass()
        {
        }

        public String MessageSender(int i)
        {
            InvokeMessage("Message: " + i);
            return "Message: " + i;
        }

        public void InvokeMessage(String mess)
        {
            if (MessageDelegate != null)
            {
                MessageDelegate(mess);
            }                
        }
    }
```

This matches your previous event delegation as it did not require an output param. This is the main difference between Action<'Tin> and Func<'Tin, Tout>. If you want your main class method to return data back to the delegate caller is when you would use Func. If i have missed something in your requirements please let me know.